# Deploying to Heroku Error foundation 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

Anyone know why am I getting this? when deploying to Heroku?

`File to import not found or unreadable: foundation_and_overrides.`

On my production.rb:

config.serve_static_assets = true

config.assets.compile = true

Thanks in advance

Comment: If error is exactly as posted it looks like a typo, you don't have file extension in there.

Comment: I don't know why it's happenning: in my application.css file I have: `require foundation_and_overrides`and the file itself is called `foundation_and_overrides.scss.css`. Any idea?

Comment: This error is during asset compilation? What happens if you try running `rake asset:precompile` on your computer?

Comment: Yes, it's during asset compilation.

2.) It gives me an error:

`Don't know how to build task 'asset:precompile'
/Users/enriqueisasi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/enriqueisasi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'`

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. It's `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Everything ok with rake assets:precompile. No errors.

Comment: Ok, only thing that comes to my mind now is that this file is not checked into git.

Comment: Solved! I redid the workflow again and worked.

Comment: And can you point the problem? Or was it something trivial?

Comment: I exactly don't know where the problem came from. What I did was:

1.) Enable assets precompilation in production.rb

2.) git add . | git commit -m "My commit" | git push -u origin master | git push heroku master |